# Wireplumber needs to be restarted for the A2DP profile to work

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, pipewire, wireplumber

I have recently bought some bluetooth earbuds (Soundcore A40). I had some problems related to the sound profile, where I could only use the HSP/HFP profile with very bad quality.

I switched from PulseAudio to PipeWire following [this guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/) and the situation got better. The only issue now is that every time I use the earbuds, I need to restart the Wireplumber service (`systemctl --user restart wireplumber`) and wait for the earbuds to reconnect.

If you need logs or any other information, I will be happy to provide them.

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm facing with the same situation

Comment: Nope, I just have created a small script to restart wireplumber and put it in `~/.local/bin`.
I run the script manually from the terminal.
Definitely not ideal, but I did not find any better solution.